# удаленное выключение пк

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

у меня есть .NET Framework приложение, которое должно удаленно выключать определенный пк(для его поиска я использую его ip адрес) если он еще находится в сети. У меня есть код который в теории это умеет делать:

```
              int waitSeconds = 00;
              string ip = .....;

              ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
              processInfo.FileName = "shutdown.exe";
              processInfo.Arguments = $@"-s -f -m \\{ ip } -t { waitSeconds }";
              processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
              processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

              var proc = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

но когда  попытался с помощью этого кода выключить сторонний пк,  то у меня ничего не вышло,(пк просто не  выключился) хотя ip адрес я ввожу правильный... может есть какой-то способ через скрипт проверить, возможно ли данный компьютер выключать удаленно? заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какой скрипт вам нужен? Вы смотрите не в ту сторону. С помощью кода можно выключить ПК, но нужно, чтобы нужный ПК смотреть в сеть (если он не в локальной сети, конечно).

Comment: То есть вы хотите выключать чужие компьютеры без ведома их владельцев? Мда...

Comment: Здравствуйте! пк находятся в локальной сети.

Comment: если проект для локальной сети то смотрите в сторону встроенных команд винды, а так если по глобальной то тебе фаерволл не позволит

Comment: Для того что вам нужно не нужно писать ни единой строчки кода. Вам в сообщество сисадминов, где точно знают как это делается. Как проверить - запустить ту же команду из командной строки.

Comment: @aepot не нужно только если выключаемый комп и комп отправляющих команду в одном и том-же домене, и есть права админа домена, во всех остальных случаях нужно либо стороннее ПО, либо аппаратные фичи навороченного железа уровня энтузиаст/сервер. Либо танцы с бубном rdp и скриптами, что при неправильном подходе открывает дыру в системе. Куда проще и безопаснее свою утилиту навелосипедокостылить.

Comment: @Blackmeser вы бы сначала поизучали тему прежде чем писать вот это вот всё. Оно работает проще, чем кажется. Ответ кстати неплохой, но он к сожалению не отвечает полностью. Как я понял, вы предлагаете использовать костыль вместо встроенных функций операционки, а это не есть хорошо. Тема чисто сисадминская, поизучайте, домены тут вообще не при чем. Но нюансы есть везде.

Comment: Всем здравствуйте! спасибо за Ваши комментарии! а если выключение сделать не получилось, то можно как-то узнать почему? попробовал через командную строку выключить другой компьютер и получил это: *Введено недопустимое имя компьютера или удаленное выключение не поддерживается на конечном компьютере. Проверьте имя и повторите попытку либо обратитесь к системному администратору.(53)*. Нельзя ли как-то это через C# скрипт получить? то есть там по сути та же команда для выключения, только как-то нужно результат работы команды получить и обработать...

Comment: а если после вызова команды shutdown, например, через 2 секунды пинговать ip адрес пк, которого я хотел выключить, и если он все еще в сети, то значит команда не сработала? и таким образом можно понять что что-то не так...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете просто так выключить чужой ПК, в комментарии выше я указал причины. Иначе мамкины хацкеры только в путь вырубали чужие компы один за другим.

0. Ваша программа должна находиться на чужом компьютере.
1. Убедитесь что ваша программа занимает сетевой порт. Для портов меньше 1000 требуются права администратора.
2. Убедитесь что ваша программа использует корректный локальный IP адрес: 192.16xxx, 172.xxx, 10.xxx ... А не 127.0.0.1 или любой другой 127.xxx. Если компьютер имеет доступ в глобальную сеть напрямую - соответственно использовать нужно глобальный IP. Или можно просто использовать 0.0.0.0 и тем самым разрешать приём команды из любой подсети.
3. На стороне выключаемого компьютера нужно занять сетевой порт для прослушки.
4. На стороне компьютера, который производит выключение - нужно нужно открыть сокет: IP выключаемого компьютера : порт
5. Если выключение производится из разных подсетей - должен быть настроен проброс порта на выключаемый компьютер.
6. При открытии порта при подключении сокета необходимо запустить функцию приёма данных, одного байта достаточно, например можно отправить 0xFF
7. На стороне приёма в функции приёма дождаться заветного байта и удостовериться что он соответствует 0xFF
8. После чего на стороне выключаемого компьютера и вызвать данную функцию с вашим ProcessStartInfo, только в параметрах без удалённого компьютера \ip

С кодом придётся повозиться, но зато без танцев с бубном и перенастройкой компов и дыр безопасности.
Если с пробросом порта на роутере - после всего этого хоть из любой точки мира выключайте ваш ПК. Код  0xFF разумеется меняйте на более безопасный, можете хоть шифрование прикрутить.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Blackmeser! спасибо за Ваш ответ! Да, тема действительно сложная, буду изучать...

Comment: @HolyWar_ а вообще самый простой способ - поставьте VNC сервер и не парьте мозги, там вам и удалённое управление, и передача файлов.

Comment: здравствуйте, Blackmeser! спасибо за Ваш комментарий! не думаю что этот вариант мне подходит, так как делаю это приложение не для себя... потенциальных пк для выключения = ~1000, и на каждый из них устанавливать VNC... Суть в том что-бы я мог сделать приложение , которое человек мог открыть(естественно на его пк) и с помощью моего приложения иметь возможность удаленно выключать много пк. Все пк находятся в локальной сети(как и пк человека, который будет все выключать)

Comment: с моей стороны нужно предоставить код, который будет работать в случае если все условия(те что Вы описали) соблюдены. Естественно нужно что-бы было какое-то предупреждение, мол, что в случае если что-то не так, то ничего не сработает... поэтому я и спрашивал, как получить и вывести результат работы команды shutdown у меня в приложении...

Comment: Если компов ~1000, это организация, следовательно они должны быть в домене, а там и стандартными средствами вырубать компы можно, если домена нет, но в сети тьма компов - это печально. Что касается ответа - в том-же соединение через сокет можно и отвечать, однако есть программы блокирующие выключение, что с ними делать я не знаю. Само простое как контролировать - да, пинговать.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Blackmeser! Спасибо за Ваш комментарий! не совсем понял Вашу фразу "а там и стандартными средствами вырубать компы можно"... Стандартными - это как? типа через команду shutdown? Еще раз - спасибо!

Comment: @HolyWar_ стандартными средствами - это как раз через команду shutdown, в домене она отлично работает.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Blackmeser! Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ! Теперь я понял```:)```